# Secondary Database Replica in Reverting/InRecovery (Long time)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

Reposted from: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/secondary-database-replica-in-reverting-inrecovery-long-time

Hi,

One of my AG secondary replica has been in reverting/in recovery for more than a day. The database size is about 700GB. I was trying to suspend/remove the database from the AG so I could apply the differential and log backups to get it up-to-date, but SQL Server wouldn't allow me to do so because it's running a HADR_DB_COMMAND that is blocking me. Is there a way to bypass this? Or, would it be best to allow SQL Server to do its thing?

Thank you.

Comment: I am running into the same issue and its best to have it recover by its own. Mine took 40 mins for 3 TB database. I have opened a case with MS and since I am running on 2014, there are limited things that I can check. 
Was the db having large transactions running when the failover happened ? Also check indirect checkpoint to see if that helps recover faster.

Comment: Have you checked [your VLFs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230663/availability-group-database-stays-in-reverting-for-too-long-after-a-failover?rq=1)

Comment: Are you seeing messages every couple of minutes in the error log about a DB recovery in progress and % complete?

Comment: There are 64 VLFs on that database.

Comment: No, there are no messages about progress.  The only way I can tell is by looking at Perfmon Database Replica: Log remaining for undo decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

I waited it out for about two days and the replication is back up.

I guess it's best to let SQL Server do it and to monitor the counters pertaining to the undo (SQLSERVER:Database Replica -> Log Remaining For Undo and Total Log Requiring Undo).